# Restarting application instances and evaluating state

Tags: command-line-interface, pcf, cf-cli

What is the best way to obtain the state of the instances of an app ?

This will return the state of the cluster,  however there may be instances that are down or starting.  `cf curl /v2/apps/{app-guid} | jq .entity.state`

I am trying to find the best way to iterate through a cluster and cycle app instances without any downtime.

Using the cf as per below,  but want to evaluate the health of the instance before kmoving on to the next instance
`cf restart-app-instance $APP_NAME $index`